# Wrong answer displayed for simple math problems c++

Tags: c++, macos, codeblocks

I am just starting to learn C++ in college and our first assignment is to make a program that will do basic math. i feel like my code is not mistaken, but when i display the variable "sum", i get an answer that is way off. the value for the answer changes even if i input the same number multiple times. for example, i entered 2 for each variable and i got 1864273973 the first time and 1772335157 the second time. what could be causing this? i am using a macbook pro and code blocks, if anyone is wondering. i have also included my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
//variabe declarations
int number, number2;
int sum, difference, product, dividend;

//calculations
sum = number + number2;
difference = number - number2;
product = number * number2;
dividend = number/number2;

//user inputs
cout << "\n1 of 2: Enter a number: ";
cin >> number;
cout << "\n2 of 2: Enter second number :";
cin >> number2;
cout << "\nNumber 1 entered: " << number << "\nNumber 2 entered: " <<    number2;

//output
cout << "\n" << number << "+" << number2 << "=" << sum << "\n";

}
```

Comment: Why are you calculating before? That affects the results because the variables are not updated and the equation is not recalculated after you store user input. Put calculations at the very end, but before you output results

Comment: `i feel like my code is not mistaken`. You feel wrong. Oh so very very wrong. Perhaps go to a few more classes before trying the prac work...

Comment: You're calculating before you get the input, which means you're calculating with uninitialized variables. How can you calculate the addition of A + B **before** you know what A and B are? *Basic math* means that you can't do calculations with two numbers before you know what the numbers are and expect to get usable results. Learn to actually read the code you're writing instead of just hammering on the keyboard.

Comment: Move the _calculations_ block after the _user inputs_ block [and before the _output_ block]. You're doing the calculations with undefined/uninitialized values. Always use the compiler option `-Wall` [and optionally `-O2` sometimes gives extra warnings]--it would have flagged this for you.

Comment: sorry I've only had 2 classes thus far, didn't realize the importance of placement. it works now. thank you.

Comment: And you definitely will want to learn to use a debugger in the not-so-distant future.

Comment: finch7591 :Can you show your corrected code?I too have a similar issue.I wrote a+b=c after the scanf function,but still i am getting same result for different inputs.I am using Codeblocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ and almost every language nowadays use a structured system. It reads from top to bottom, so if you say "a = b+c" and then cin >> a, the calculation from b+c will be lost after the new input. 
You are trying to calculate using variables that are declared but not initialized. In c++, this will cause the new variable to just receive "trash", a number you probably don't want. To correct this, I think you want to actually receive number and number2 BEFORE doing the math.

Comment: 'this will cause the new variable to just receive "trash"' - actually, it is undefined behaviour, so *anything* could happen to *any* part of the program.